# Drag-and-drop of a mail window in Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook-2016

Is it possible to drag the window of a mail M1 and drop it to the window of a mail M2 in Outlook 2016 in order to attach M1 to M2 ?
If so, how ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can drag-and-drop one stored email into a email being drafted by simply opening the draft in another window, having a list with the stored email  open in your outlook menu window, and then dragging and dropping the stored email onto the email being drafted, saving the stored email as an attachment.

Comment: I thank you for your answer. Is it possible to drag a mail from its window and not from a list ?

Comment: No, but you can copy the contents of an email and paste it onto a different email! If you want to screenshot the email, you can use your computer's "Print Screen" function. Here is a link for that: https://www.howtogeek.com/226280/how-to-take-screenshots-in-windows-10/